# How do I use a Postgres JDBC connection from WebLogic?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, weblogic, classloader

I am trying to use a Postgres JDBC connection from WebLogic 14.1.1. I have added the Postgres JDBC jar to my domain's `lib` folder and added a datasource using the management console. The 'test' button at the end of the process indicates success. So far, so good.

However, when I try to actually use the connection, I get a ClassNotFound exception regarding some sort of WebLogic wrapper class. Here is the full stack trace:

```
    ####<Feb 23, 2023, 10:40:21,445 AM Central European Standard Time> <Error> <HTTP Session> <MacBook-Pro.local> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <fb856892-8489-4b11-beea-d232c77f0c0c-00000024> <167>
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection
        at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:225)
        at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:190)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory$1.run(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:178)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:175)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.allocateConnection(Driver.java:229)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.connect(Driver.java:157)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionData.getConnection(JDBCSessionData.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionData.getSessionIds(JDBCSessionData.java:128)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionContext.getIdsInternal(JDBCSessionContext.java:246)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.cleanupExpiredSessions(SessionContext.java:703)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator$1.run(SessionContext.java:680)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.timerExpired(SessionContext.java:676)
        at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:677)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:219)
        at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:190)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory$1.run(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:178)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:175)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.allocateConnection(Driver.java:229)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.connect(Driver.java:157)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionData.getConnection(JDBCSessionData.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionData.getSessionIds(JDBCSessionData.java:128)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionContext.getIdsInternal(JDBCSessionContext.java:246)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.cleanupExpiredSessions(SessionContext.java:703)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator$1.run(SessionContext.java:680)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.timerExpired(SessionContext.java:676)
        at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:677)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

I have located that `PoolConnection` class in the `com.bea.core.datasource6.jar` file under the `modules` folder under my WebLogic home folder. I have tried adding this jar to my domain's lib folder as well, but then the entire server refuses to start.

The strange thing is that the `weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory` that tries to load the file comes from the same jar file, and that apparently can be found just fine.

I have no problems adding connections to Oracle databases, just Postgres is giving this issue.

Comment: I still don’t know why, but it’s working as expected on an actual production-like server. It’s only broken on my local development instance. I still need to investigate which difference actually causes the problem.